# Cocos2d-x. How to add action on the sprite after the previous one was finished

Tags: action, cocos2d-x, sequence

I add action on the sprite.

```
auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(2, Vec2(moveX, moveY));
_Spr1->runAction(moveBy);
```

I want to add another action on touch, but I want that the second one started after the first one is finished.

And if I tap two times before first action stops, I want to create sequence with one old action and two new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about queue your following actions, wait the current actions finish, and then add them?

[Check if animations are still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582481/check-if-animation-is-running-in-cocos2d-x)

Comment: Yes, I chose this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto moveBy1 = MoveBy::create(2, Vec2(moveX, moveY));

auto moveBy2 = MoveBy::create(2, Vec2(moveX, moveY));

auto *seq = Sequence::create(moveby1,moveby2, NULL);

_Spr1->runAction(seq);
```

Comment: No, I want that when this Sequence "seq" is started and not finished yet, add moveBy3 action to this Sequence.

Comment: then try Spawn function.using spawn you can run two action simultaneously.

Comment: Spawn *spn = spawan::create(moveby1, moveby2); and ad this spn into the seq function